# Why one should not consecrate water to Lord Hanuman?

Tags: worship, hanuman

I went to a temple about a few weeks ago. On the wall of this temple, it was written that it is prohibited to consecrate water to Lord Hanuman according to scriptures. At that time, I could not ask priest about this and did Google around a little bit, but did not find any reference to this. Does anybody know about this?

P.S. Varun deva had blessed him with a boon that he can never be harmed by water.

Comment: I think its Varuna deva not Vayu deva...

Comment: @Tezz corrected it

Comment: But i have seen many temples which do consecration of water, milk etc., every week. Those temples strict rules in worship. I think it is not prohibited.