# Why oil is offered to Lord Hanuman's feet?

Tags: hanuman

We offered ghee or milk to other Lord like Shiva, Rama in their head. Then why we offered oil on Lord Hanuman's feet?

Comment: I have asked for why oil is offered on Lord Hanuman's feet. I have already know that oil is offered in Saturday. So, it can't be duplicate.

Comment: Related [Why one should not consecrate water to Lord Hanuman?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12230/5212)